.NET Upgrade Assistant - How generate report for target .NET Standard 2?
My colleagues and I are in the early stages of incrementally upgrading a large ASP.NET Web Forms enterprise app to ASP.NET Core, the supporting libraries will be upgraded to .NET Standard 2.0.
To help us we are using the.NET Upgrade Assistant extension in Visual Studio.
For the .NET Framework 4.7.2 => .NET Standard upgrade, we want to use the report feature to overview the issues to solve. However it seems we can only generate report with target .NET 6, 7, 8 etc.
I have looked around but did not find the correct documentation or an answer. Does anyone know if target Standard 2.0 report is supported? And in that case, how to generate it?
If unsupported, are there alternative tools? I know Microsoft has had other tools for porting, but I have lost track which are not obsolete tbh.
In VS we right click the solution, choose upgrade, choose new report, but there is no option for .NET Standard.
.NET Upgrade Assistant report feature in VS
This is in Visual studio 2022 community in Windows 11.

When I say report, I mean the report feature of Upgrade Assistant. We want to get information on which dependencies will be a problem to upgrade from .NET Framework 4.7.x to .NET Standard 2.0, and hints about actions to take.

As mentioned in this document,  we can guess that the target Standard 2.0 should not be supported.
Supported .NET upgrades:
.NET Framework to .NET 6+ (including .NET 9.0 Preview)
.NET Core to .NET 6+ (including .NET 9.0 Preview)
Any .NET version to .NET 6+ (including .NET 9.0 Preview) that is higher than the current version

But The future of .NET Standard says, NET Standard 2.1 will be the last version of .NET Standard,.NET 5 and all future versions will continue to support .NET Standard 2.1 and earlier.
.NET 5 as the combination of .NET Standard & .NET Core

It combines and replaces the netcoreapp and netstandard names.Since there is no difference between the standard and its implementation, you’ll be able to take advantage of new features much quicker than with .NET Standard.You should think of net5.0 (and future versions) as the foundation for sharing code moving forward.

It is not wise to migrate into .NET Standard 2.0 as it is already announced that there won't be any new version after .NET Standard 2.1 but only .NET 5+. .NET 5+ replaces the .NET Standard. I suggest you are migrating better to go for latest version .NET 6.
If you want to target .NET Standard 2, you can migrate to .NET 6 with the Upgrade Assistant. Then, downgrade to .NET Standard 2.0 from the project properties.
Hope it can help you.

Thanks a lot for the feedback, do you have a link to the document with the supported upgrades? Although, it might be out of date, at least upgrading a class library to .NET Standard 2 is possible with the Assistant, it just is not possible use the generate report feature.
The idea of migrating our class libraries Standard 2.0 is to reference from both the old Web Forms app, and the new ASP.NET Core app. Would be amazing to use everything great from the latest version of C# and .NET all at once, but we judged a big bang upgrade and rollout as un-smart.

Please check the following link:
.NET Upgrade Assistant
Upgrade Assistant blog post

Microsoft answered in the Q & A of the Visual Studio Marketplace page for Upgrade Assistant and confirmed that it is not supported yet, but is a planned feature.

"It will come in next versions. We just started with analysis and there are many scenarios that we have not implemented yet."

VS Marketplace Upgrade Assistant page
